# How can i fix the find_all error while web scraping?

Tags: python, html, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am kinda a newbie in data world. So i tried to use bs4 and requests to scrap data from trending youtube videos. I have tried using soup.findall() method. To see if it works i displayed it. But it gives me an empty list. Can you help me fix it? [Click here to see the spesific part of the html code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxfRA.jpg)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/explore")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
soup.prettify()
trendings = soup.find_all("ytd-video-renderer",attrs = {"class":"style-scope ytd-expanded- 
shelf-contents-renderer"})
print(trending)
```

Comment: this WILL NOT work, you didn't even define `trending`, it should be `trendings`

Answer (score 2):

This webpage is dynamic and contains scripts to load data. Whenever you make a request using `requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/explore")`, it loads the initial source code file that only contains information like head, meta, etc, and scripts. In a real-world scenario, you will have to wait until scripts load data from the server. BeautifulSoup does not catch the interactions with DOM via JavaScript. That's why `soup.find_all("ytd-video-renderer",attrs = {"class":"style-scope ytd-expanded-shelf-contents-renderer"})` gives you empty list as there is no `ytd-video-renderer` tag or `style-scope ytd-expanded-shelf-contents-renderer` class.
For dynamic webpages, I think you should use **Selenium** (or maybe Scrapy).
For Youtube, you can use it's API as well.

Comment: Even with selenium it's hard to pull this off

Comment: I don't think so. You just need to put your selenium driver on sleep for few seconds (until page fully loads) after `driver.get(url)`. Then you can get page source from `html = driver.page_source` and use it with beatifulsoup or you can use selenium functions to extract data.

Comment: I have tried that, for some reason it doesnt work